# Wamp server php.ini file

Tags: php, wamp

I just downloaded and installed the wamp server but the file `php.ini` file can not be found anywhere although the configuration page shows

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini
```

I was wondering if somebody knows the root cause.
Is it possible to get the file from somewhere for that version?

Comment: In official PHP distributions you can find two templates called "php.ini-development" and "php.ini-production". No idea of how Wamp handles that but you can try and search for those names, just in case.

Comment: Did you try locating the file php.ini from wamp server tray icon?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález php.ini-development etc are just template files, if you want to use them you need to rename them to php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get that file really easy. It's a php configuration file. If you know your installed php version go to [PHP net](http://php.net/downloads.php)
and download it for your version.

In there you will find `php.ini-production`(production settings) and `php.ini-development` (development setting better suited for debugging). Pick one and rename it to php.ini (php as name for file and ini being extension). Now you are ready to go after you copy it to your installation folder.

Make sure to resart your server after applying the changes.